# Cross-Referencing Variables, And, Compiling Projects

Tags: python

I am attempting to make a login system for a sort of text adventure game I am making. I've noticed that when executing the login file from outside my editor it does not recognize variables I put in the configuration package (see screenshots). I imported them from the package, and it works inside the editor, however, when taken out into terminal, it no longer recognizes it. I feel this might be something with my code not being compiled into a single executable.

This leads me to my second point: how would I export my project into a single file? (Perhaps it opens terminal, Contacts my User Identification Handler, and, then continues into the main script--the one that would actually contain the text adventure.) Essentially:

```
User Opens Program:
    All Files Are Loaded
      The "Register" File Is Loaded To Identify The User
        A Main Script Is loaded (yet to be created, will probably be in the first directory, not its own package)
```

My Project In The Editor
[image]

Terminal reads:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zachary/IdeaProjects/Python/Text-Adventure/DataHandler/Register.py", line 2, in <module>
    from config import variables
ImportError: No module named config
```

Comment: Please, provide text version of terminal output, can't figure out, what is displayed on it

Comment: @MihanEntalpo
Check Edit

Comment: If "config" module is placed in the same folder, where Register.py, you can try to change your import to "from .config import variables" (notice the dot, added before "config")

Comment: Thanks! I will move them to the same directory and try...at the moment they share a parent directory, EX: ParentDirectory contains DataHandler (Register.py) and Config (variables.py). If I understand you correctly, you want ParentDirectory contains DataHandler (Register.py & Config [variables.py])

Comment: please, look at my answer, there are a better way than moving your all modules that need config to a single directory

Answer (score 0):

Your Register.py is located in the DataHandler folder. When you're using import from some local module, it should be located in the same folder or in some subfolders. You cannot import module from upper folder (actually you can, by specifying path at runtime, but this is not recomended practice).

So, you have two solutions:

1) Place Register.py in folder, where config folder, or variables.py file located. Then use "from config import variables" or  "import variables", depending on existence of "config" folder.
 
**This is not the best solution**, because, you'll have to place all your modules into a single folder, where config is accesible.

2) **Better solution**: in your Register.py create a class, that would take "variables" as an argument in the __init__() method. In your root __init__.py file import this class, and variables.py (as __init__.py is located in the root folder of the project, it can access all the modules in subfolders), and create an instance of Register class, passing variables to it's constructor.

So, you'll solve your initial problem, and your code would be more decoupled and maintanable (you need to pass **variables** to the Register constructor, but you don't neet to store **variables** in the file, you can move it to the database table, or to the Redis later, if you need)